# Plotting decision boundary of Logistic Regression (liblinear)

Tags: regression, logistic, classification, svm, libsvm

I have liblinear model file for a classifier learned using logistic regression. In the file, they say, the weight vector and intercept term.  But when I simply plot it as 
$$w^Tx + b$$
on the original data,  it does not seems like the proper decision boundary. But in case of SVM, plotting

$$w^Tx+b$$ seems to be the correct way.  Is there any difference in case of Logistic Regression with liblinear ?

Answer (score 4):

Logistic regression does not have decision boundaries.  It is a method to estimate probabilities of events/class membership.  Decisions are made in a separate step once you know the estimated risk along with utilities/costs/loss function, which is the way optimum decisions are made.

Comment: but if i am not mistaken, it is among the linear classifiers, and the probability of class membership is decided based on $$\frac{1}{1+exp(-f(x))}$$ where $$f(x) = w^Tx+b$$, which is a linear decision boundary.

Comment: That would be true if "decision" were part of logistic regression.  It is not.

Comment: what do you mean by "decision" being part of logistic regression ?.  In normal settings (without any thresholding), the decision is similar to the case of SVMs, right ?.  +ve, $$if p(x) \geq 0.5$$ (similar to $$f(x) >= 0$$

Comment: I said that "decision" is *not* part of logistic regression.  The construct you wrote which uses a highly arbitrary 0.5 risk threshold is not part of logistic regression.  Logistic regression is a direct probability estimator.

Comment: Ok. In that case, what is the $$w$$ and $$b$$ in the logistic model file ?. What is the plane $$w^T+x$$ corresponds to ?

Comment: The plane provides the log of the odds of the probability that $Y=1$ given $X=x$ ignoring the intercept.  In this sense think of an equation to predict height as a function of age and interpret that equation.  There are no boundaries.

Comment: Sham - the *level sets* of the estimated probability are linear. Any selection of a decision boundary by choosing a level set is a later step, subsequent to the actual logistic regression (which is not of itself actually a classification tool).

Comment: Glen_b, in that case, suppose i chose a level set corresponds to the probability value 0.5, then plotting

Comment: sorry, how can i plot decision bounday corresponds to this decision

Comment: That is at odds with what logistic regression is trying to do, and a 0.5 threshold is completely arbitrary.